# Git: git diff show changes, but merge says up to date?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

So I have two branches: master and other. I merged other branch into master, but for some reason source for one commit have not changed.

I can see those commits in master by running `git log`, but actual source code have not changed. In `other` branch it has new changes, but `master` does not.

So running:

```
git diff master..other dir_name
```

Shows me this:

```
--- a/dir_name/views/purchase_order_report.xml
+++ b/dir_name/views/purchase_order_report.xml
@@ -60,9 +60,9 @@
                     <span t-field="o.partner_id.name"/>
                     <div t-field="o.partner_id"
                         t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address"], "no_marker": true}'/>
-                    <t t-if="o.partner_id.child_ids.search([('type', '=', 'invoice')])">
+                    <t t-if="o.partner_id.child_ids.filtered(lambda r: r.type == 'invoice')">
                         <span>Attn: 
-                            <span t-esc="o.partner_id.child_ids.search([('type', '=', 'invoice')])[0].name"/>
+                            <span t-esc="o.partner_id.child_ids.filtered(lambda r: r.type == 'invoice')[0].name"/>
                         </span>
                     </t>
                 </div>
```

`+` lines are the ones that should be in master too, but are not for some reason.

And doing:

```
git checkout master
git merge other
Already up-to-date.
```

So it seems something is messed up.

**Update**. I also cherry picked some commits from `master` to `other` branch. Maybe that caused some issues too?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch says there are some commits in `master` that are not in `other`. `git-merge` merges actual commits - the fact that you have different files doesn't mean they're not merged.

Try running:

```
git checkout other
git merge master
```

and see whether the file is changed. If it is, it's exactly due to what I described above.

Edit: if you want to have the changes from `master` in `other` just for this file, you can either find the commits that changed the file on `master` and cherry-pick them (google `git cherry-pick` - note that this would introduce entire commits, which might be undesirable in your case), or apply them manually. There is no way to get "just this file" via merging.

Comment: Yes there are differences from master that are not in other branch. But I don't want those changes in `other` yet. The point of that is, `master` branch is used to have all the changes. And `other` is branch that came from stable branch which is a bit behind from `master` (in other words I now develop a feature/fix from branch which came from stable branch). Maybe that logic is a bit messed up, but that's what I have now :)

Comment: No, I need the opposite. There are changes from other branch which did not apply to master even though I did merge and I see that commit in master...

Comment: Did you by any chance merge `other` to `master` and then revert the merge commit?

Comment: I probably had done that in a past, but then I merged it again and it merged fine.

Comment: This is not how merging works. Merging ensures that commits (not changes) are available. If you make a merge, and then push a reverting commit, the commits that set the content are merged, so these won't be reapplied in future merges.

Answer (score 0):

Try *git cherry master other*, which outputs '+' or '-' followed by commit-sha1 that are already in the history of other but not yet in master. You can just ignore the '-' lines and focus on the '+' lines. '-' means the master has not merged the commit but has got already an equivalent patch(applied by git am, git cherry-pick or git rebase). '+' means the master has not merged the commit and has no equivalent patch.

and then *git log other -- dir_name* to see if any '+' commit-sha1 is in the output.